# How to trigger newlines in log messages?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

**Is it possible for log messages to span multiple lines?** I am expecting:

`RAISE WARNING 'Line 1\nLine 2';`

to result in the following log:

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

But instead I get:

`Line 1\nLine 2`

Any ideas?

Comment: Read about [escape string syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE) and [`standard_conforming_strings`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS) in the manual.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's the same as any other string. Either use non-standard `E''` strings to tell PostgreSQL you want escape processing:

```
RAISE WARNING E'Line 1\nLine 2';
```

or use SQL-standard strings with literal newlines:

```
RAISE WARNING 'Line 1
Line 2';
```